# Is it possible to request for multiple cabs using Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

I am developing a web app where I integrated Uber APIs. Now, I would like the user to request for multiple cabs using Uber APIs from our app. Is it possible to request for multiple cabs using Uber API from our app anyway?

Answer (score 1):

No, the same user cannot request multiple Uber rides at the same time, this would return the following error: 
"409 current_trip_exists    The user is currently on a trip."

And is documented on our developer documents here:
https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post